# File Encryption and Decryption using AES in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new in iOS app developing. I need to encrypt and decrypt the files in ios using objective-c. While i am searching i got string encrypt and decrypt only.

```
CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,/* kCCEncrypt, etc. */
                                     kCCAlgorithmAES128, /* kCCAlgorithmAES128, etc. */
                                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, /* kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, etc. */
                                     keyPointer, kCCKeySizeAES256,/* key and its length */
                                     ivPointer, /* initialization vector - use same IV which was used for decryption */
                                     [encryptedText bytes], [encryptedText length], //input
                                     buff, buffSize,//output
                                     &numBytesEncrypted);
```

Here how can i encrypt and decrypt the files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for file encrypt and decrypt using AES. I maintain same code for both encrypt and decrypt for files using crypt type. if we pass the crypttype as 1 the file encrypt using aes. If we do decrypt we can pass the value as 2.

FileAes.m

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(encryptDecryptFile:(NSString *)crypType
                  appkey:(NSString *)key
                  inputPath:(NSString *)inputPath
                  outPutPath : (NSString *)outputPath
                  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    if ([[SecurityUtil encryptDecryptAESFile:crypType app_key:key input_path:inputPath output_path:outputPath] length] <= 0) {
        reject(@"ERROR", @"decrypt failed", nil);
    }
    resolve ([SecurityUtil encryptDecryptAESFile:crypType app_key:key input_path:inputPath output_path:outputPath]);
}
```

SecurityUtil.m

```
+(NSString*)encryptDecryptAESFile:(NSString*)cryptType  app_key:(NSString*)key input_path:(NSString*)inputPath output_path:(NSString *)outputPath
{
    NSLog(@"file input path===> %@",cryptType);
    NSString *res;
    NSData *decryedData;
    @try {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:inputPath];
     if(cryptType == @"1"){
            decryedData  = [data AES128EncryptFileWithKey:key ];
       }else{
            decryedData = [data AES128DecryptFileWithKey:key ];
        }
        //NSData *decryedData = [data AES128DecryptFileWithKey:key gIv:key];
        [decryedData writeToFile:outputPath atomically:YES];
        res =@"success";
        return res;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception in decrypt File==> %@", exception.reason);
        res=@"failure";
        return res;

    }
    @finally {

        NSLog(@"Finally condition=== %@",res);
        return res;
    }

}
```

NSDataAesFile.m

```
- (NSData *)AES128DecryptFileWithKey:(NSString *)key  {//FileDecrypt
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    memset(ivPtr, 0, sizeof(ivPtr));
    [key getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//gIv

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"crypt status==> %d", cryptStatus);

        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

The above code is working for me. May be it will help.